# Loss function with derivative in TensorFlow 2

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I am using TF2 (2.3.0) NN to approximate the function y which solves the ODE:  y'+3y=0

I have defined cutsom loss class and function in which I am trying to differentiate the single output with respect to the single input so the equation holds, provided that `y_true` is zero:

```
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomLossOde(Loss):
    def __init__(self, x, model, name='ode_loss'):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.x = x
        self.model = model

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(self.x)
            y_p = self.model(self.x)


        dy_dx = tape.gradient(y_p, self.x)
        loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(dy_dx + 3 * y_pred - y_true))
        return loss
```

but running the following NN:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from custom_loss_ode import CustomLossOde


num_samples = 1024
x_train = 4 * (tf.random.uniform((num_samples, )) - 0.5)
y_train = tf.zeros((num_samples, ))
inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(16, 'tanh')(inputs)
x = Dense(8, 'tanh')(x)
x = Dense(4)(x)
y = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)
loss = CustomLossOde(model.input, model)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.99),loss=loss)
model.run_eagerly = True
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=30)
```

for now I am getting 0 loss from the fisrt epoch, which doesn't make any sense.

I have printed both `y_true` and `y_test` from within the function and they seem OK so I suspect that the problem is in the gradien which I didn't succeed to print.
Apprecitate any help

Comment: When you are passing `model.input`as a `x` of your custpm loss, what exactly are you trying to achieve? `model.input` is a symbolic tensor, it does not contain any data.

Comment: @Lescurel As I have said: I am trying to define a loss function which is repented on the derivative of the (single) network output with respect to the (single) network input. Can you explain how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a custom loss with the high level Keras API is a bit difficult in that case. I would instead write the training loop from scracth, as it allows a finer grained control over what you can do.

I took inspiration from those two guides :

- [Advanced Automatic Differentiation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff#higher-order_gradients)
- [Writing a training loop from scratch](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch?hl=en)

Basically, I used the fact that multiple tape can interact seamlessly. I use one to compute the loss function, the other to calculate the gradients to be propagated by the optimizer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Input

num_samples = 1024
x_train = 4 * (tf.random.uniform((num_samples, )) - 0.5)
y_train = tf.zeros((num_samples, ))
inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(16, 'tanh')(inputs)
x = Dense(8, 'tanh')(x)
x = Dense(4)(x)
y = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)

# using the high level tf.data API for data handling
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train,(-1,1))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train)).batch(1)

opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.99)
for step, (x,y_true) in enumerate(dataset):
    # we need to convert x to a variable if we want the tape to be 
    # able to compute the gradient according to x
    x_variable = tf.Variable(x) 
    with tf.GradientTape() as model_tape:
        with tf.GradientTape() as loss_tape:
            loss_tape.watch(x_variable)
            y_pred = model(x_variable)
        dy_dx = loss_tape.gradient(y_pred, x_variable)
        loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(dy_dx + 3 * y_pred - y_true))
    grad = model_tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_variables))
    if step%20==0:
        print(f"Step {step}: loss={loss.numpy()}")
```